# Mutable Variable in Class -- Issue

Tags: c++, mutable

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Test
{
  public:
    int x;
    mutable int y;
    Test() 
    { 
      x = 4; y = 10; 
    }
   static void disp(int);
};

void Test::disp(int a)
{
    y=a;
    cout<<y;
}

int main()
{
    const Test t1;
    Test::disp(30);
    t1.y = 20;
    cout << t1.y;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error with in the constructor:

```
void Test::disp(int a)
{
    y=a;
    cout<<y;
}
```

I don't understand why this is not working because y is mutable and its already updated successfully within constructor Test() but when its coming to disp(). its shows error..

I have also checked with some other examples also . So I came to know you can update a mutable variable once only. If you try to update it more then one time it shows an error. Can anyone explain why this happening or reason behind it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: invalid use of member 'Test::y' in static member function abc.cpp....

Comment: Can you also tell , Is updating a mutable variable more then once is  possible or not ?? Because i think this error only came when u are trying to update a mutable variable more then once .....

Comment: You can't access a non-static member in a static function.

Comment: Can we update mutable variable value more then once.......???

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with `mutable`. You are trying to modify a non-static class member from a static method, which is not allowed. In your example it makes little sense to have the `Test::disp` method static in the first place.

You also seem to have misunderstood the meaning of `mutable`. It doesn't make members of a const object non-read-only. It makes it possible for const methods to write to members. Your code updated to show what mutable does:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Test
{
  public:
    int x;
    mutable int y;
    Test() 
    { 
      x = 4; y = 10; 
    }
   void disp(int) const; // Notice the const
};

void Test::disp(int a) const
{
    y=a; // ::disp can write to y because y is mutable
    cout<<y;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    t1.disp(30);
    t1.y = 20;
    cout << t1.y;
    return 0;
}
```

And yes, there is no limit to the number of times a mutable variable can be written, just to be clear.